# Changing US percentage in German percentage

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is that I'm using the German version of Excel and my inputs are in US number format.

I need a code that changes all points in decimal percentage numbers, to a coma but keeps the percentage format as cell value.

```
Sub Makro1()
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

When I use this simple macro to change all periods into commas then the value of the cell gets formatted as text but I need it in percentage.

Comment: What is the source of these values? where do they come from? If you paste them you can change the Excel file decimal sign from `,` to `.` so it accepts that as values instead of text and later change it back to `,`. In a german Excel you find that option at: Datei > Optionen > Erweitert > Bearbeitungsoptionen > Dezimaltrennzeichen and change it to `.` instead of `,` then insert your values (*Trennzeichen vom Betriebsystem übernehmen* has to be deactivated at first)

Comment: Thnks, I know that I can change this in the options but I dont want to change it everytime when I import new values.And my problem is that I need the values with a coma. Isn´t there a code that can just change it? The source of my values are intrest rates from the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I just made a Makro changing the opionts to DecimalSeparator to "." and then back to "," and it works.

But thanks for your help!

```
Sub Makro1()

    With Application
        .DecimalSeparator = "."
        .ThousandsSeparator = ","
    End With
End Sub

Sub Makro2()    
        With Application
            .DecimalSeparator = ","
            .ThousandsSeparator = "."
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant to do. Note: you can accept your own answer as solution too.

Comment: Thanks, dind't knew that!

Answer (score 1):

*It has to be said, that this is a cumbersome workaround and I recommend to change the decimal sign in Excel options (before inserting and back after) instead of using this code.*

The issue use that `Replace` returns a string not a value.
So you need to convert the string into a number.

**Example for values like `55.52`**

```
If IsNumeric(Selection.Value) Then
    Selection.Value = CDbl(Replace(Selection.Value, ".", ","))
End If
```

---

**Example for values like `55.52%`**

```
Dim Text As String
Text = Selection.Value

If Right$(Text, 1) = "%" Then
    Text = Left$(Text, Len(Text) - 1) 'remove % sign
    If IsNumeric(Text) Then
        With Selection
            .Value = CDbl(Replace(Text, ".", ",")) / 100
            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"  'change number format to percent
        End With
    End If
End If
```

Note that we need to divide the value by `100`, because `0,5552` represents `55,52 %`.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. I put in a picture how it looks when I have insert the values. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: This would only work best by changing the Excel Option as I told you in my comment. My code works only for values like `55.52`. For values like `55.52%` you would need to remove the percent sign first and format the cell as percent later with `.NumberFormat`.